# Question on Heyting algebras

Tags: logic, intuitionistic-logic, heyting-algebra

Does $a \Rightarrow b = 1$ iff $a≤b$ hold for any complete Heyting algebra? If not, please provide a counterexample.

Comment: Just some feedback on the question: you have received quite a few downvotes as well as upvotes. The question itself is interesting, and I happen to know your motivation for it, which is a good motivation. However, you have not explained this in your question, which makes it look a lot like you are just posting a homework question where you have not done any effort. So try to include your own thoughts, or the motivation for your question. Including context will not only result in more upvotes and less downvotes, it will also allow answerers to cater more to your specific problem or interest.

Comment: Thanks Mark! Next time I will take more time and elaborate the context!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; in fact, the Heyting algebra need not be complete.

If $a \leq b$, then $1 \land a = a \leq b$, so $1 \leq a \Rightarrow b$. Therefore, $1 = a \Rightarrow b$.

If $a \Rightarrow b = 1$, then $1 \leq a \Rightarrow b$, and therefore $a = 1 \land a \leq b$.